# How to control packet generation rate and send interval

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to create an UDP application where the packet generation rate and packet send interval can be controlled separately.

My code is in https://github.com/11187162/udpApp

With the above code, I am not getting the expected outcome and getting the following runtime error:

> scheduleAt(): Message (omnetpp::cMessage)sendTimer is currently
> scheduled, use cancelEvent() before rescheduling -- in module
> (inet::UdpOwnApp) SensorNetworkShowcaseA.sensor3.app[0] (id=176), at
> t=0.058384669093s, event #10

The code for handleMessageWhenUp() is given below.

```
void UdpOwnApp::handleMessageWhenUp(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (msg->isSelfMessage()) {
        ASSERT(msg == selfMsg);
        switch (selfMsg->getKind()) {
            case START:
                processStart();
                break;

            case GENERATE:
                generatePacket();
                break;

            case SEND:
                processSend();
                break;

            case STOP:
                processStop();
                break;

            default:
                throw cRuntimeError("Invalid kind %d in self message", (int)selfMsg->getKind());
        }
    }
    else
        socket.processMessage(msg);
}
```

Would anyone please help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written that *"generation rate and packet send interval can be controlled separately"* but you use **the same self-message** for control generation of packets as well as for sending of the packets. When a self-message is scheduled it cannot be scheduled again.

Consider adding a new self-message for generation of packets.

By the way: `numGenerate` is set to zero and it is never changed.

**EDIT**

Assuming that `selfMsg1` is used for generating packets only the following code may be used:

```
void UdpOwnApp::handleMessageWhenUp(cMessage *msg) {
      if (msg->isSelfMessage()) {
        if (msg == selfMsg) {
          switch (selfMsg->getKind()) {
            case START:
                processStart();
                break;
            case SEND:
                processSend();
                break;
            case STOP:
                processStop();
                break;
            default:
                throw cRuntimeError("Invalid kind %d in self message", (int)selfMsg->getKind());
            }
        } else if (msg == selfMsg1) {
            if (selfMsg1->getKind() == GENERATE) {
                generatePacket();
        }
        }
      }
    else
        socket.processMessage(msg);
}
```

And in `initialize()` you should create an instance of `selfMsg1`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Regarding adding a new self message, if i add ```cMessage *selfMsg1```, and schedule that, will it work? Would you say a bit more why ```numGenerate``` is never changed? Is it because i had to increment it? Thank you

Comment: You may add `cMessage *selfMsg1` in header file, schedule it when you want and change `handleSelfMessage()`. According `numGenerate` - I have just noticed that it will always be equal to zero, so it is useless. It is never changed because in your code you only assign zero to it and you do not change its value. I don't know what is the meaning of this variable. BTW: link is inactive. You should avoid external links - try to add the code to the question.